# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn0MQ.png)

When I tried to Insert this

```
Insert into Title
    (ISBN, Title, CategoryCode, PublisherCode, SuggestedPrice, NumberInStock)
Values
    ('1021031040', 'PL SQL', 1, 200, 75.50, 10)
```

I got this message and I could not figure it out. Could someone help me, please?

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Title_PublisherCode_To_Publisher_PublisherCode". The conflict occurred in database "Lab2A_Daisuke_Sato", table "dbo.Publisher", column 'PublisherCode'.

Comment: There is no PublisherCode 200 in your Publisher table. That is the reason you cannot insert into the title table with such a code. It has to exist. That is actually a basic SQL principle. You should take a SQL tutorial.

Comment: @DaleK I'm not going to bother asking the asnwerer below because they obvs don't care, but how is this not an exact dupe??

Comment: @DaleK No I didn't know, congratulations. Use it well (like voting: early and often)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your insert statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO Title (ISBN, Title, CategoryCode, PublisherCode, SuggestedPrice, NumberInStock)
VALUES ('1021031040', 'PL SQL', 1, 200, 75.50, 10);
```

The error message seems to be saying that there is no record in the publisher table whose primary key is `200`.  That is, your insert is referring to a publisher record which does not exist.  The remedy would be to either not do this insert, or to add a record to the publisher table with an id of `200`.